# How to run home grown app as root

Tags: sudo, application-development, gui, root

I have developed a GUI app that I sometimes want to run as root. In Ubuntu 18.04, I used sudo with no problems, but in 20.04, sudo will not run the app: with no error message. Also, if I run sudo su, and then try to open the app from the command line, nothing happens. And I see no relevant log messages. What changed related to running an app as root from 18.04 to 20.04, and how can I run my app as root?

Update: I added a trace statement that writes to a file as the first line of code in the main.cpp. Nothing is written to the file when the app is run as root. As far as I can tell, none of my code is executed when I run the app as root. Running the app as "normal", the trace is executed and the app works as expected. The app uses GTKmm. All other libraries are standard system or C++14 libraries. When I first tried this in 20.04, there were no system log messages. Now (after numerous system updates) the log shows "pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root" when I run it under sudo, and no messages at all after I sudo su, i.e. becoming root. I have another GTKmm app that works when run as root in 20.04. Since none of my code is executed in the app that does NOT run in 20.04 as root, I'm not sure how to track this down. I also don't know if this is a bug in 20.04 (and may be fixed) or an intentional change from 18.04. Any suggestions would be welcome. Thanks!

Update2:
Running (as was suggested) with strace showed me that a file path changed when the app is run under sudo. I don't know why that causes a problem without running any code that references it, but at least I found the problem. I assume that **the getenv("HOME") function changed from 18.04 to 20.04** so that it now returns the root home instead of that of the current system user when the app is run as root. I will need to search for another function that will return the current system user. Thanks for your help!

I was getting the users home directory via getenv("HOME") and using the user name therein. That worked in Ubuntu 18.04, but was changed in 20.04 to be /home/root when the app is run as root. A solution is to obtain the user name from getlogin(). From that, I can construct the home directory.

Comment: are you sure the log messages are irrelevant?

Comment: The log messages say that Tracker was successfully launched. Tracker is a search assist tool. There are no messages relating to security.

Comment: When I upgraded from 18.04 to 20.04.1, I immediately found bugs. Is this problem a bug in 20.04? Or did the security change, preventing locally developed apps from running as root? Does anyone know? Thanks.

Comment: your question is going to have to be edited to show a lot more information about the problem than what you provided there. Youre basically asking everyone to guess.

Comment: you'll need to add some debugging output in your app's code to see where it gets stuck - you could also run an "strace yourapp" to see what system calls it's doing